# How to save JPasswordField char in MYSQL datable

Tags: java, mysql, swing, prepared-statement, jpasswordfield

I am writing an access control program in Java that captures passwords using `JPasswordField`. Since the `jpasswordfield.getPassword()` method returns values as chars, I need to know how to save the char value in a MYSQL database using `preparedstatement`. I am using MYSQL fields `password char[100]` for storing the passwords.

Please help.

Comment: Please, don't store plain text passwords in your database.

Comment: please give good and secure practice advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to store password in database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple example of storing a char array in a database using a prepared statement. I used Java DB instead of MySQL as it is included in the JDK (jdk1.7.0/db/lib/derby.jar) it shouldn't matter for this example.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:memory:sampleDB;create=true");
             Statement statement = connection.createStatement()
        ) {
            char[] pw = "password".toCharArray();
            statement.execute("create table sample(pw char(10))");

            try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from sample");
                 PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into sample values (?)")
            ) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                    preparedStatement.setString(1, new String(pw) + i);
                    preparedStatement.execute();                    
                }

                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As others already said, you should not store passwords in plaintext in the database. Instead you should store a hash of it ([SHA-1 Hash in Java](http://www.anyexample.com/programming/java/java_simple_class_to_compute_sha_1_hash.xml)).

Comment: Yes, you can store the password using SHA-1, but, how do you get the typed password from the passwordfield as getText() is deprecated and getPassword() doesn't give you a String to handle ?

Answer (score 0):

use some password encryption algorithms to save password ,it would be good practice  ,google it for details,